# For demultiplexing: why datagram socket needs to know only Source-Port and Destination-Port, but no Source-IP and Destination-IP?

Tags: sockets, network-programming

I am confused on why Datagram socket needs to know only Source Port and Destination Port, while TCP socket keeps 4 valued tuple:

- Source-Port
- Source-IP
- Destination-Port
- Destination-IP

Why we can send some datagram without knowing the receiver IP address?

Comment: Why do you think datagrams can be sent without the receiver IP address?

Comment: You are mistaken. It does need to know the source and destination IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

When sending data on a connectionless/datagram socket, the receiver's IP address is usually specified in the `sendto` call.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740148%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The sendto function is normally used on a connectionless socket to send a datagram to a specific peer socket identified by the to parameter. Even if the connectionless socket has been previously connected to a specific address, the to parameter overrides the destination address for that particular datagram only. On a connection-oriented socket, the to and tolen parameters are ignored, making sendto equivalent to send.

Connectionless sockets, by definition, don't connect to a peer, and thus it is not necessary to specify the receiver's address until data is actually sent.

Note that calling `connect` on a connectionless socket is in fact allowed, but rather than connecting to a remote host it just sets up a default destination IP address, which will then be used in subsequent `send` calls on that socket.